# Unable to run flutter doctor command in visual studio code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

i am trying to run the command flutter doctor on visual studio terminal but i got this error :

> lutter doctor -v
> bash: /Users/users/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter: Operation not permitted
> exit code 126

how could i solve it ?

Comment: any other command do the same? for example `flutter --version`? or `flutter --help`?

Comment: i got the same message : Operation not permitted

Comment: `ls -l /Users/users/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter` - most likely it does not have `x` (execute) bit set

Comment: i got this response : -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 users  staff  2345 Jun 14 15:36 /Users/users/Downloads/flutter/bin/flutter

Comment: yes , but on the terminal i have no problem but when it comes to Visual studio code , i can execute flutter doctor